# Configuring CentOS Apache Server for IP Based VirtualHost?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, virtualhost

I'm running CentOS 5.6 on my server with Apache.  I need to create a "staging" site so that client can view the development in progress.  I understand that this is done via Apache virtual host.  Where is this file located on the server?

Since we have 1 IP address on the test server, and we don't want to change DNS for the domain name just yet, how do I setup the virtual host to resolve the http://my.ip.addy to our test server's /var/www/html/public directory?

Thanks much for your guidance.

Comment: It sounds like you need multiple domains going to different sites while using the same IP, right?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.  test.ourdomain.com is needed right away, and eventually ourdomain.com will be pointed to this server when dev/test is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to get a domain name to resolve to an IP as well as getting the computer at that IP to respond appropriately. To do that you want to modify your httpd.conf file, which is located at `/etc/httpd/conf/` by default. You would then add the following at the bottom:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> # note the asterisk.
ServerName staging.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
ErrorLog logs/staging.example.com-error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

For `ServerName` you put whatever you want as a domain. Changing the `*:80` to `your.ip.add.ress:80` means that the machine will only respond by the `ServerName` provided if the request is to that IP (You may want that too, but I generally avoid it).

Then, on the client side, I would modify the [`hosts`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) file to point that domain to the IP of the testing server. This will let you navigate to the domain and arrive at the testing site. It might be something like this:

```
127.0.0.1         localhost loopback
::1               localhost
your.ip.add.ress  staging.example.com
```

Comment: On my hosts file, I have 127.0.0.1 localhost our.ip.addy test.ouraddy.com Do I need the entry ::1 localhost as well?  When I browse to test.ouraddy.com I am unable to resolve to the test server.  Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: ::1 is your IPv6 local host address. As for the other entry, you need to i has 127.0.0.1 test test.ouraddy.com. Don't remove the existing local entry, to avoid breakage.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration file is */etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf* and you can use the minimal virtualhost as follows,

```
<VirtualHost X.X.X.X:80>
ServerName staging.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
ErrorLog logs/staging.example.com-error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

More Info: http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-apache-config.html

Comment: Will that allow us to hit the server via http://our.ip.address ?

Comment: Normally, the first virtualhost domain will be served when accessing the IP when you host multiple virtualhosts on the same IP. So, if there is only one virtualhost, I guess you got it :)